# Using linq to filter a list from a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am generating two lists with int values and select all ids of list one not found in list 2 using linq:

```
var clerkRole = db.Roles.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Clerk");
List<ApplicationUser>lstUser = db.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Select(y => y.RoleId).Contains(clerkRole.Id)).ToList();
List<int> lstUId = lstUser.Select(c => c.Id).ToList();

var alldps = db.Deposits.Select(a => a.UserId).Distinct().ToList();

var clerkNotIn = lstUId.Except(alldps).ToList();  // error here and below
```

I get the following error:

> Error 25  'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'Except' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Except(System.Linq.ParallelQuery, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments

Could you help? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm betting you are missing the Linq namespace, add this at the beginning:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Also change the `var` to be sure that UserId is an `int`.  This won't have any effect except if UserId is not actually an `int`, then you'll get an error indicating UserId is not an `int`:

```
List<int> alldps = db.Deposits.Select(a => a.UserId).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks the error was because the userId was nullable  I added .value to it and error resolved